# Linkedin autofill button not getting displayed for safari/iphone mobile browsers

Tags: linkedin-api, autofill

We are using script:

> https://www.linkedin.com/autofill/js/autofill.js

To display the autofill with `linkedin` button in our page.

But because we have this regular expression check when we open our page in iphone mobile `browsers/safari` the autofill button is not getting displayed.

We want to know the reason why we have added this check in autofill.js script.

```
var isSafari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
 if (isSafari)
 {    
   // do not run autofill inside safari   return; 
 }
```